# Is there any option to debug xamarin android application quickly?

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new with xamarin development, debugging too time to get ready with view. After made tiny changes, need to build the application it takes 2-4 minutes get ready with view on Simulator or Emulator.

Secondly, if we are using xaml view and we want to made changes in design, after change or add the properties we can not view the UI without run. Is there any way we can see the view of form?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, there is no way to do it more quickly.
One way is to however, increase your processing speed by getting a new cpu or overclocking it. Also, have enough RAM for running both your OS and the Emulator on the same PC, or use a real device to debug.

While in XAML view, click the "Design" tab on the bottom left hand corner of the XAML view area. That should show you the UI without having to run the Android Application.